# Code Compliance with Objective-C view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement the CAS login objective-C code to my current Xcode project but I keep having code compilation errors everytime I try to get the text from one of my IBOutlets the error comes up. Here is the code for the CAS View Controller:
[CASViewController.m - Look at the username and password strings that's where the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNREI.png)

[CASViewController.h - the username and passwords swift IBOutlets are hat connect the storyboard to code and which are causing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnFbj.png)

I am new to swift so I've been looking around to get this working. I have made the CAS client a static linked library and I have made a bridging file to connect the code however I am still at a loss. Thank you in advance for the help.

the error I am getting:

error is:2017-07-03 12:31:22.520 SAF[2947:45298] Unknown class _TtC11CAS library17CASViewController in Interface Builder file. 2017-07-03 12:31:22.530 SAF[2947:45298] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:

Comment: 1. Don't add code as image. Always use text. 2. What error?

Comment: sorry I don't use stack overflow often and the error is:2017-07-03 12:31:22.520 SAF[2947:45298] Unknown class _TtC11CAS library17CASViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-07-03 12:31:22.530 SAF[2947:45298] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fd794908c00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key authResultMessage.'

Comment: Please add the error message to your Q as text. Look, if someone sees your Q and wants to help, likely he does not want to grab all information from the comments. Put every necessary information to the Q. This helps others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel IBOutlets` are missing the required connection. You need to connect them to the labels in `Storyboard`'s `UIViewController`.

Specifically, UILabel `authResultMessage` isn't connected to Storyboard. Use `Ctrl+drag` to connect it with relevant label in Storyboard.

Comment: I created links to the other outlets but they still aren't working. I believe the error comes from my CASViewController I took it out of the CAS Library project

Comment: The error you posted above states that you're missing a class CASViewController in Storyboard. So yes, your Storyboard doesn't compliance with the class. Assign it in Storyboard.

Comment: Okay I see is there a way for me too segue from one storyboard view controller to another story board view controller in another Xcode project?

Comment: Not in another XCode project, but yes in the same project you can make multiple Storyboards and segue between different View Controllers.

Comment: Bilawal, so I would have to move the story board and other files from the other project to my project?

Comment: Yes, Of course. Btw if my answer helped you in any way, you may mark it as correct and helpful. :)